# pandas convert index values to lowercase

Tags: python, pandas

I want to convert index values of a pandas dataframe to lowercase. Please use this to test:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([1, 2, 3], columns = ['c'], index = ['A','B','C'])
```

Comment: `map(str.lower, index)`, would work for you.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use the vectorised [`str`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#string-handling) method [`lower`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.lower.html#pandas.Series.str.lower):

```
In [115]:
df.index = df.index.str.lower()
df

Out[115]:
   c
a  1
b  2
c  3
```

**EDIT**

For versions older than `0.16.1` (thanks to @Joris for pointing that out) you can call `map` and pass the `str.lower` function:

```
In [117]:
df.index = df.index.map(str.lower)
df

Out[117]:
   c
a  1
b  2
c  3
```

Comment: tried the same before posting but I get an error: ----> 3 df.index = df.index.str.lower()

AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'str'

Comment: Note: this is only available starting from 0.16.1, so for older versions you will have to use something like `df.index.map(str.lower)`

Comment: ... then I read somewhere that index must be converted to series because vectorised string ops only work with columns. What pandas version are you using?

Comment: @grokkaine I'm using version `0.16.1` so it should work if you upgrade, otherwise try the `map` method in my updated answer

Comment: You're so fast at answering pandas questions, why don't you give the rest of us a chance? :p Seriously, good answer +1

Comment: @firelynx I have time during compiling my cpp projects to browse the pandas questions ;-)

Comment: doesn't work with multiindex.

Answer (score 0):

The [rename](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) function is handy here, in conjunction with [str.upper](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.upper):

```py
df.rename(str.lower)
   c
a  1
b  2
c  3
```